# android ffmpeg .so download

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

Anybody knows from where to get compiled .so FFMPEG library for Android?

I tried thousand of times to compile the FFMPEG manually on windows-7 using Android NDK
but never succeeded.

So I think it's better to use precompiled lib as I'm already using the same same technolgy that used in:
https://github.com/guardianproject/SSCVideoProto

But the ffmpeg lib in this project is very old.

Any help is much appreciated.......

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was built to `ffmpeg 2.0` since integrate with `android-ndk-r9b` [`Download the prebuilt *.so`](https://www.mediafire.com/?81luapelsre53fl).

`set up *.so file` :

> 1 - Add folder jni/libs/*.so
>
> 2 - Use "Right-click mouse" -> Android Tools -> Add native support -> Set name of file *.cpp
>
> 3 - Two files : *.cpp and Android.mk appeared.
>
> 4 - Use Cygwin to build & compile *.so into the project.

[`How to load another .so file in your android project?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063397/how-to-load-another-so-file-in-your-android-project/20063480#20063480).

@Sanket Excute command need know this first before transfer parameters to the C++ method :

[Calling C++ method in C++ file from Java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607042/unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-calling-c-method-in-c-file-from-java-file?noredirect=1#comment34431151_22607042)

Comment: Link to .so file doesn't work.

Comment: Really sorry, I updated again.

Comment: Prebuilt .so link broken

Comment: @Pete : Already updated again

Comment: dropbox inner file libffmpeg.so file is version2.0 or higher?

Comment: sorry, how I can know the version? I don't know clearly what you mean

Comment: actually i require 2.0 or higher becz directly excuting command in thread

Comment: Ah I see. The version of Dropbox, right? My Dropbox version is 2.4

Comment: sry actually ffmpeg 2.0+ higher build .so file . plz updare .so file

Comment: How to build or integrate library in android plz help or give me update ffmpeg2.0 file plz help thanx in advance

Comment: Okay, I will tell you how to build ffmpeg.so file through [the link](https://vec.io/posts/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-android-ndk). Should build on Linux OS. I believe you will be succeed if you understand how it works.

Comment: ya i know i am already using this way generating .so file but i m executing command i.e /data/data/packagename/libffmpeg.so and command getting error exit value 11. how to executing ffmpeg command  Plz Help how to execute command after .so file generate

Comment: You mean how to load file *.so into eclipse? Read my answer for this question again please.

Comment: I Alex - you are update so file  in dropbox but how to this so file using command execute plz help or plz add some step to directly execute command

Comment: `how to this so file using command execute` I updated new answer. How to transfer parameters to the C++ method, you should learn more.

Comment: Thanx @AlexTran . It's possible to directly your updated ffmpeg.so file used in Processbuilder using execute command.

Comment: plz can you update the link

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the `libffmepg.so` from the `Dolphin Player` builds

https://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/downloads/list

Rename the package extension to `.zip` and extract the `.so` libraries from `lib` folder.

Comment: dropbox inner file libffmpeg.so file is version2.0 or higher?

Comment: Hello I have just libffmpeg.so file as you suggested. now how can i execute ffmpeg command?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you two ways:

**#1:**
you can download the project given [in this blog](http://dmitrydzz-hobby.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-build-ffmpeg-and-use-it-in.html)
. It works just fine, start adding your code in this project.

**#2:**
you can build with your own. The easiest way is to build within Linux. You can choose any of the version releases for android from [here](http://bambuser.com/opensource)
. After extracting you will find a README.txt file. The steps described there are quite straight forward. Follow them, you will get the build I believe.