# Ffmpeg build android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Executing build_android.sh in cygwin below error generating

```
C:/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.
If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.
build_android.sh: line 61: make: command not found
build_android.sh: line 62: make: command not found
build_android.sh: line 64: C:/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar: No such file orirectory
build_android.sh: line 66: C:/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld: No such file orirectory
```

please help how to handle this type of error

Comment: You try to build ffmpeg.so file, right? If you need, you will take much time to build successfully. Therefore I think you should see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732174/android-ffmpeg-so-download/20087603?noredirect=1#comment33169563_20087603) , get the *.so file, put it to Eclipse, and use.